# rest_post_query on multiple post types?

Tags: rest-api

how do you get the rest_post_query filter to work across multiple post types? I'd like to modify the orderby for all post types but at the moment i have to specify "post" in the filter name, which means it doesn't work on the custom post types i've created?

```
add_filter("rest_post_query", function ($args) {

    $args["orderby"] = "menu_order";
    $args["order"] = "ASC";

    return $args;

}, 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the callback as a named function and hook it separately for each post type.

```
function wpse_299908_order_rest_query( $args ) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'menu_order';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'wpse_299908_order_rest_query' );
add_filter( 'rest_page_query', 'wpse_299908_order_rest_query' );
```

There's no filter that automatically applies to all endpoints, likely for the same reason that you can't query multiple post types at once to begin with. [As discussed](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2567) during development of the API:

> Because each custom post type is modeled differently, it's not
>   possible to fetch them from the same endpoint in v2. Conceptually,
>   it's like fetching users and posts from the same end point — it
>   doesn't make much sense.